# how to direct different message to diferent Topics in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I have producers with different topics configured to it. and all the producers are listening to a same file, which gets multiple events per sec, all the events are different from each other. please find the below sample.

`A event1
B event2
C event3
A event4
C event5
B event6
D event7
E event8
F event9
E event10`

considering each event as 1 message. how to direct different messages to their corresponding topics from the list of producers that are listening to the event file.

Thanks.
Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the Kafka documentation?

- https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi
- https://kafka.apache.org/0102/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html

Assuming that `A`, `B`, etc. are the names of the desired destination topics, simply replace "my-topic" with `A` etc. in the code below:

```
Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>("my-topic", "my-key", "my-value");
```

Comment: Thanks Michael.here A, B, etc are messages from different devices. so I need to send the A,B etc message to the topics that I have created for each of the them. problem I face is all the devices send the log to a same file. I have a key field to differentiate the log by device, as mentioned earlier the A, B, etc. are the differentiators.

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me then what your problem is.  Perhaps you need to update/improve the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have a single Kafka producer that listens to the input file and publishes to different topics based on the content of each new event written in the file?

Comment: that's a good approach but I have 1000 different types of events. and the EPS(events per sec) band width is very high 1gb per sec.